# Android Adobe Reader - Display PDF from web

Tags: android, pdf

I have an android application that needs to display the pdf files. For this I am using Adobe PDF reader intent and pass the file path to it.

It works fine when the pdf file is present on the sdcard but I am not able to view the pdf file when it is placed on web (i.e. http://www.myweb.com/pdfs/mypdf1.pdf).

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Adobe Reader on Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.reader) does not seem to support this feature so far, as it is really simple.

Maybe you could try [Adobe Air](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7eb4.html), but I am not sure [the version on Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.air) supports .pdf.

If not, I suggest you could pass the Intent to the browser, and the browser will download it, and then it can be displayed. Maybe there will be some browser that can open .pdf directly as those do on computer, but I am not aware any.